# Can I have two entry points in C#

Tags: c#

Would it be possible to use two entry points in C# instead of just having the one. For example when I have this:

```
using System;
namespace learning
{
    class cool
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to have another entry point such as secondary that the program executes once the main entry point has finished.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting

Comment: To format code, the trick is to indent it with 4 spaces.

Comment: And no, you can't have two entry points in your program. You can only have one. If you want additional code to be executed you will have to call a method with that code yourself.

Comment: Just write two methods. In Main just call the first method and then the second one. You will achieve the same results as if there were "two entry points"

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do something like this:

```cs
class Program {
    public static void EntryPoint1(string[] args) {
        // Code
    }
    public static void EntryPoint2(string[] args) {
        // Code
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        EntryPoint1(args);
        EntryPoint2(args);
    }
}
```

Just make sure to not modify args during EnteryPoint1 or if you want to, clone them like this:

```cs
class Program {
    public static void EntryPoint1(string[] args) {
        // Code
    }
    public static void EntryPoint2(string[] args) {
        // Code
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        EntryPoint1(args.Clone());
        EntryPoint2(args.Clone());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you specify the entry point using the /main: compiler option.
Imagine that the code containing containing two main() methods as follow :

```
namespace Application {
class ClassA {
    static void main () {
        // Code here
    }
}

class ClassB {
    static void main () {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

To use ClassA.main() as your entry point, you would specify the following when compiling:

```
csc /main:Application.ClassA hello.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single entry point, but you can write two separate methods, call the first one, and then the second one. You will achieve what you're describing.

```
using System;
namespace learning
{
    class cool
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PartOne();
            PartTwo();
        }

        void PartOne() {
            // Something happens here
        }

        void PartTwo() {
            // Something else happens here
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally (depending on how the program starts up) you can send in arguments to specify *which* method you want to execute (if you don't need both of them to execute). Then you can just do an "if/else" statement that will decide which method to run depending on the arguments passed into `Main`